# Criar determinada sequência numérica, armazenando em ArrayList

Tags: java, algoritmo

Preciso desenvolver um algoritmo em Java que retorne a seguinte sequencia:

> 9, 16, 25, 36, 49...

Ja identifiquei que o padrão é o seguinte:

```
9 = 3²
16 = 4²
25 = 5²
36 = 6²
```

Os valores precisam ser armazenados em um `ArrayList` e serem exibido ao final.

Comment: De onde virão esses numeros? Há algum padrão esperado nessa sequencia? O que você já tentou fazer? Veja que sua pergunta continua com os mesmos problemas das outras.

Comment: Por isso quero saber como esse tipo de algoritmo funciona, para entender como essa logica e formada

Comment: Vou te dar uma dica de como elaborar uma pergunta no minimo, aceitavel aqui no site, respondendo a estas questoes: O que eu pretendo fazer? O que já tentei fazer? Quais problemas estou tendo ao fazer? Criando uma pergunta respondendo corretamente a isso, dificilmente sua pergunta será ruim.

Comment: Descobrir a logica para a sequencia 9, 16, 25, 36, 49. Procurando algoritmos de sequencia.

Comment: Pronto, publicação editada.

Comment: A sequencia é só até 49? O programa recebe algum valor?

Comment: Pode aprar no 49 mesmo. Sim, recebe o valor incial int n.

Comment: Pode usar funções prontas para potencia como da classe Math? Ou tem que ser tudo feito sem usar classes prontas?

Comment: Não precisa usar a class Math.

Comment: for(int i=3; i < limite; i++){ System.out.println(i*i); }

Comment: Pode ma ajudar a inserir esses resultados em um ArrayList e depois imprimir ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tente assim:

```
    int valorInicial = 3;
    int n = 7;
    ArrayList<Integer> lista = new ArrayList<>();
    // usando math
    for(int i = valorInicial; i <= n; i++){
        lista.add((int)Math.pow(i,2));
    }

    for(Integer num : lista){
        System.out.print(num + " ");
    }
```

ou sem usar a classe `Math`:

```
    int valorInicial = 3;
    int n = 7;
    ArrayList<Integer> lista = new ArrayList<>();
    //sem usar math
    for(int i = valorInicial; i <= n; i++){
        lista.add(i*i);
    }

    for(Integer num : lista){
        System.out.print(num + " ");
    }
```

Neste link do [ideone](http://ideone.com/TL4GPG), você pode ver o resultado(que será o mesmo) dos dois métodos em funcionamento.

Comment: Pode me ajudar a colocar isso em um ArrayList e depois imprimir ?

Comment: @RafaelAugusto editei, veja agora se atende.